# How is /proc/<pid>/cmdline related to the argv variable of a process?

Tags: linux, argv, procfs

When I run a process and the content of argv[0], this also changes the content of /proc//cmdline. Now I checked in the kernel code in fs/proc/cmdline.c, and the cmdline_proc_show function there seems to get its content from the global saved_command_line variable. However I didn't find how saved_command_line is related to the argv array. Does anybody know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/proc/cmdline` relates to a kernel command line and info from `boot_params`.

For user processes there are `cmdline` files in subdirs named with a process-id `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`; shell example: `cat /proc/$$/cmdline`.  A series of struct pointers leads to process command line args; for details see `proc_pid_cmdline_read()`

note: some symbols may differ between releases

Comment: Ah right, so cmdline_proc_show in fs/proc/cmdline.c handles /proc/cmdline, whereas proc_pid_cmdline in fs/proc/base.c handles /proc/<pid>/cmdline. And that simply accesses the argv variables in the process' virtual memory. Awesome, thanks a lot!